# How do I implement lemmatization on a large amounts of data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, lemmatization

I need to implement lemmatization on a large amounts of data(~10 million lines). Python nltk library is very slow on large amounts of data. Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Use clearNLP or stanford-coreNLP. clearNLP (http://clear.colorado.edu/compsem/) is considerably faster.

Comment: Is there a benchmark for comparing this platform? Also is there a python wrapper for clearNLP?

Comment: Stanford coreNLP (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.0661v1.pdf, http://www.oegai.at/konvens2012/proceedings/60_rodriquez12w/60_rodriquez12w.pdf) is the best NER tagger where as the clearNLP has the fastest parser. Both are in Java, and clearNLP also has clearTK end to end system based on UIMA (used by IBM watson, the one that beat the humans in speed and accuracy in Jeopardy :)). So if you are using clearNLP/clearTK you can call on other best tools in NLP like stanford coreNLP etc.; not so easily for nltk given it is python.